# os.environ doesn't show all environmental variables in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, environment-variables

I am finding that the following code prints out my expected environmental variable when I execute the script in a shell:

```
import os
print(os.environ['STUFF'])
```

However, when I run this same code in Jupyter Notebook, I get a key error. I have tried restarting the Jupyter server. What else should I do?

Comment: Have you tried printing *all* the environmental variables within the Jupyter notebook and seeing if `STUFF` is defined? It is likely that the notebook has a different set of variables than your command line does.

Comment: do you start your jupyter server from the terminal?

Comment: 1) Which OS? 2) How are you launching the jupyter notebook? 3) Where did you set the environmental variables? In `.bashrc` or similar? Assuming that: 1) you are using Ubuntu or an other linux distro, 2) that you are executing the notebook directly without starting a shell 3) That you set the environmental variables in `.bashrc` or similar I suggest you read [Persisent environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables) and modify your `~/.pam_environment` or `~/.profile` file accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can query all the dictionary keys to confirm the one you have is not there.

```
import os
print(os.environ.keys())
```

Or better you can test for the presence of the specific key.

```
print(os.environ.has_key('STUFF'))
```

Comment: The key error already confirms that the key isn't there. This may be useful as a comment but doesn't answer the question.